# Free SQL comparison tool

Tags: sql, database

I have been using SQL Compare by Redgate at my company and was very satisfied with it. Are there any free comparison tools that are similar? Or what would be my best shot for synchronizing two SQL db's without a paid application

Comment: Toad is the only other tool I'm aware of that provides this, but its not free.

Comment: go for http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/releases/view/72756 
It is free and does the trick!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’ve gone through this and couldn’t find anything comparable, free or otherwise. $395 is a very small price to pay for the value the tool brings and it will almost certainly pay for itself very quickly in productivity gains and risk minimisation.

Comment: alternatively, create a virtual machine (e.g. in Hyper-V) that you'd install the Red-gate software and delete after expiry to create a new one. This takes only about 10 minutes. Redgate supports sync using backups .bak. when comparing schema.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and wanted a free GUI base Schema comparer tool, what I found was
Star Inix (http://www.starinix.com/sqlcompare02.htm).  Obviously not as good as Redgates offering, but it does the job.

Also, with Redgate Sql Compare, once the trial period is over, if you enter the key as "i need more time" (without the quotes) you can extend the trial by a further 14 days.

Comment: This is a brill free tool frin Starinix

Comment: Requires running SQL Server 2008 in backwards compatibility mode to account for ANSI character used in query (*= , =*) ...uninstalled in the end

Comment: Also works with other Redgate products (tested with ANTS Performance Profiler).

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio (Premium & above I guess) has this feature built-in under the SQL menu.

Answer (score 7):

[xSQL Free Bundle](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/LiteEdition.aspx)

Very similar to RedGate's SQL Compare and free.

Comment: The limitations on this are that a) unlimited use with Sql Express editions only b) limited to 25 tables or 40 SP's or 40 Functions or 40 Views for any other version of Sql Server.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention that. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5):

You can try using TableDiff , that came with SQL Server 2005.

[Tablediff Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

[SQL Server 2005 TableDiff Utility](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3594926/SQL-Server-2005-TableDiff-Utility.htm)

Bye.

Comment: Only problem with Tablediff is that there's no GUI with it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Mighty Comparer](http://agilewheels.ro). It's currently free. A professional version is under development.

Answer (score 2):

I normally go for the hackish but surprisingly effective technique of downloading the [sys_information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) tables to text files and diffing them with your favorite diff program (this way will even let you compare 3 schemas!).

Comment: this sounds interesting.. will definitely try!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Database Comparer](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/dbcomparer.asp)

Database Comparer is free for non-commercial use.