# Merging data between databases

Tags: sql, database, merge, migration

Suppose I have two distinct databases with identical schemas but different data. I want to merge the data between the two databases by adding the data from one into the other. Foreign key relationships, etc. need to be maintained when the data is migrated.

Are there any tools (or databases that have built-in tools) to make this job fairly simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Red Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_compare/index.htm)**

Best tool I have found for this type of thing, hands down.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built into Windows Team System (the database edition or the suite). I have tried both this and an older version of Red Gate's SQL compare and both are awesome to work with. There are also some free tools (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352600/free-sql-comparison-tool) thread) but I do not have experience with any of them

Answer (score 1):

2 options that I know of:

1. You can use [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx). For instructions on how to compare data take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn266029(v=vs.103).aspx).

2. Another option which is [xSQL Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql). For an explanation on how to use it, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514895/merging-two-databases/39252526#39252526).

Disclosure: I'm affiliated to xSQL

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team/Database versions have schema/data comparison tool.